# HP 255 G3 running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, drivers, atheros

I can't seem to get my Atheros wireless card to connect. I plugged in an Ethernet cable and applies my updates and checked driver updates but I can't get this laptop to connect wirelessly. What am I missing please help.

`sudo lspci` just states I have a Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 card it won't let me post images

```
$ sudo rfkill list
Soft blocked: no 
Hard blocked: no
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31930/discussion-on-question-by-trey-hp-255-g3-running-ubuntu-12-04-lts).

Answer (score 0):

I had an hp laptop, and suffered with similar problems, you can try these things:

1. if you are dual booting, restart from windows rather than shut down. This works in most cases, if its showing wifi disabled by hardware switch
2. Plugin your Ethernet cable. Go to settings -> software and updates -> additional drives, there you might find needed driver to download and install.
3. Sometimes there is a firmware missing. When you boot up ubuntu, after showing ubuntu logo, some text lines appear quoting firmware/driver missing. Search for that firmware online. My broadcam firmware was missing and downloading one fixed it.

These steps helped me, if they don't work for you, i will try finding some other ways.

Comment: Thanks for the help I have tried all of that though and I'm out of options. I'm going to try installing Linux Mint and see what happens

Comment: were you getting any firmware missing at the time of boot up?

Comment: No just rebooted and no firmware is missing it runs perfect with the Ethernet cable just can't get it to recognize the wireless

Comment: @Trey Mint won't help you there; it's built on Ubuntu and doesn't change much below the graphical level, so every hardware working with Mint will also work with Ubuntu, if set up in the same way.

Comment: So what are my options at this point I would prefer to run a Linux based OS I switched from Windows 10.1 which I hated and now I cannot connect to my wireless internet

Comment: can you post, what you see when you click on wifi button. Whether it shows hardware disabled or what? a screenshot would be better.

Comment: I don't get anything when I click my wifi button. The Bluetooth also is down it says it is a hardware issue which leads me to believe I don't have the drivers for anything yet. Can't post a screenshot I just joined this chat room sorry

Comment: Is there not a way for it to automatically check drivers like Windows does and update them

Comment: not the hardware button, the one you seen on the screen besides power and time. Click on it, take a screenshot, share on imageur or something and share the link. It will help a lot.

Comment: no it doesn't do that automatically and right now it seems, it can't identify the hardware or probably there is no driver for the hardware in its repository.

Comment: Dhruv here is a screen shot of the wifi button .....      http://imgur.com/VU0rMxM

Comment: can you come on TeamViewer ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get your wifi working using backports

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2015/09/03/backports-20150903.tar.gz
tar -zxvf backports-20150903.tar.gz
cd backports-20150903
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

After a kernel update the backports will need to be reinstalled with

```
cd backports-20150903
make clean
make defconfig-wifi
make
sudo make install
```

And reboot

Comment: Thanks Jeremy. I installed Mint 17.1 and it is working fine but if I decide to run Ubuntu again I'll try it.